# Javascript : place a number into an array, splitted into segments

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

I have a custom HTML slider made with the Angular CDK. It works with a drag and drop. It is vertical, the original position is at the bottom. This slider is divided into 10 segments, each of equal size.

I am able to get the slider handle position, and the slider total height.

The slider will be used to determine a color and is made of 10 colors. It should be the full height of the page (which means I can't use ticks like any normal slider would do).

Let's assume the total height is 600px, and the handle position is randomly generated.

I would like to be able to know in which segment the handle is dropped (given by the handle position).

I have used the method in the following snippet, but I don't find it very efficient.

Would someone be able to tell me if there is a better way ? Or even an array operator that would exist for that ?

```js
const interval = 600; // Slider total size
const segmentsNb = 10; // Total number of segments
const segmentSize = interval / segmentsNb; // Size of a single segment

function doTheThing() {
  const nb = (Math.random() * 600); // random number generation to simulate slider handle pos
  let pos = -1;
  let index = 0;
  
  do {
     if (nb > segmentSize * (index + 1)) {
       index++;
       continue;
     }
     pos = index;
  } while(pos === -1 && index <= segmentsNb);
  
  console.log('number is', Math.round(nb), 'at position', pos);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="doTheThing()">Do something</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take

```
Math.floor(nb / segmentSize)
```

as you see. Maybe you need to adjust the

```js
const interval = 600; // Slider total size
const segmentsNb = 10; // Total number of segments
const segmentSize = interval / segmentsNb; // Size of a single segment

function doTheThing(nb) {
  //const nb = (Math.random() * 600); // random number generation to simulate slider handle pos
  let pos = -1;
  let index = 0;
  
  do {
     if (nb > segmentSize * (index + 1)) {
       index++;
       continue;
     }
     pos = index;
  } while(pos === -1 && index <= segmentsNb);
  
  return [pos, Math.floor(nb / segmentSize)].join(' ');

}

for (var i = 0; i <= 600; i++) document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += [i, doTheThing(i)].join(' ') + '\n';
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same process for getting the position:

```
Math.ceil((segmentsNb / interval) * nb))
```

This should return the correct position.

Comment: Your solution works well but the other one has a snippet to verify it (I still have verified yours though). I also find the other cleaner than yours. I have upvoted both, but will mark the other one as accepted, sorry ... Thank you for your answer anyway !